# Controlling JavaFX ToolBar size when adding / removing items

Tags: javafx, resize, toolbar

I am using a BorderPane to place 4 toolbars at all the cardinal points i.e. top, left, right, bottom. When a toolbar expands to accept its 1st item, this growth does not revert when the toolbar becomes empty. I'd like it to shrink to its initial state when it nothing's in it. Manually setting the width or height does nothing, as I'm sure these are being handled by its layout.

Edit: I've added images to show what I mean

[image: 1]

*Initial state (empty toolbar, I set **fx-border-color** to red)*

[image: First item added]

*First item added*

[image: 3]

*Item removed, showing a toolbar that didn't revert to initial form*

Comment: Can you add some code which shows the behaviour?

Comment: hi ItachiUchiha. This happens on boiler plate code i.e. toolbar.getItems().add(new Button). then toolbar.getItems().remove(0). The toolbars get added via the border pane's setTop, setLeft, setRight, and setBottom, methods. My images show a vertical toolbar, but this happens on a horizontal one as well. If it helps, this BorderPane in turn is a child of a StackPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToolBar` is not a pane, so it may have different laying out logic behind. Actually it seems it is designed for showing some button control permanently.

Instead of setting the size of it, you can hide it at all when it has no items to show:

```
toolbar.visibleProperty().bind( Bindings.isNotEmpty( toolbar.getItems() ) );
```

**EDIT:** Full example

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar();
    toolbar.setStyle( "-fx-border-color: red" );

    toolbar.visibleProperty().bind( Bindings.isNotEmpty( toolbar.getItems() ) );

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    borderPane.setLeft( toolbar );
    borderPane.setTop( hbox );

    Button add = new Button( "add" );
    add.setOnAction( ( ActionEvent event ) ->
    {
        toolbar.getItems().add( new Button( "dummy" ) );
    } );

    Button remove = new Button( "remove" );
    remove.setOnAction( ( ActionEvent event ) ->
    {
        toolbar.getItems().remove( 0 );
    } );

    hbox.getChildren().addAll( add, remove );

    final Scene scene = new Scene( borderPane, 800, 600 );
    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();

}
```

Comment: Hi Uluk, sorry for only getting to this now. Yeah, I thought of this as well, but while it does hide the toolbar, the space it takes is still "occupied" i.e. the issue remains. I wonder about how to go back to the initial state where the toolbar took up no space, kind of like how in Swing, we use methods to force a revalidation and/or repaint of the UI. Perhaps, removing the toolbar entirely would do the trick, but that's just too kludgy a solution.

Comment: Yup, removing it and adding it back when it receives a new first child item, worked. I wish there was a better way.

Comment: @AdamLaw. Well on my testing code it is not occupied a space. See edited code.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to give me a test. i'll check on it as soon as I can. I'm on the road right now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem, though it may not be the best solution in the long run.

Since I found no way to revert back to a toolbar's size when it was first empty, I added a change listener to the toolbar's items to remove it from the layout if it's empty, and restore it, when it isn't empty anymore, like so:

```
        leftToolbar.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Node>(){

        @Override
        public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Node> c) {
            if(leftToolbar.getItems().isEmpty()) {
                borderPane.setLeft(null);
            } else if(borderPane.getLeft() == null) {
                borderPane.setLeft(leftToolbar);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Uluk's answer is more elegant, so I've switched the accepted answer over to his.